# Get mongotop metrics into prometheus

Tags: mongodb, monitoring, prometheus, query-performance, percona

Is there any way to get mongotop metrics (collection wise query count and response time) into prometheus. None of the available prometheus exporters for mongodb seem to provide this data.
Nosqlbooster provides this feature using mongotop.

Answer (score 2):

Found it finally. Percona's mongodb exporter for prometheus exports the top metrics -
mongodb_mongod_top_count_total
mongodb_mongod_top_time_seconds_total
 upon passing the flag  --collect.topmetrics to the exporter's binary.